# Show that if $C$ is a vertical line segment $c≤y≤d$ and if $F$ is a function of 2 variable defined on $C$ then $∫_CF(x,y) dx=0$

Tags: calculus

Show that if $C$ is a vertical line segment $c≤y≤d$ and if $F$ is a function of 2 variable defined on $C$ then 
$∫_CF(x,y)  dx=0$

I understand that I need to use the definition of line integral to show this is true. When I draw it out I can see that this is a vertical line, so I can't do any projection to the plan parameterized by $f(x,y)$, so the area should be zero. However, I don't know how to use the definition

$$\int_C f(x,y)dx =\int_a^bF(x(t),y(t))||((x'(t),y'(t)) ||$$

to show it formally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change from the ds integral to the dx integral. (I'm not exactly sure what tools you're allowed to use in your course, or what your definitions are, so it's hard for me to be more specific.) Then, based on your parametrization, you'll be able to see that a change in s results in no change in x (because x is constant on the curve C), so the dx integral will just be 0.

Comment: From my understanding , if $C$ is just a normal graph, then I can project $C$ onto the plane that parameterized by $f(x,y)$, so i will have a curvy wall, which I can divide into many rectangle with the heigth is the the change in $y$ or I can say $dy$ and the base is the change in $x$ or $dx$, and the line integral is just the sum of area of all these rectangle. In this case since $x$ doesn't change $dx=0$ so the base of the rectangle is zero, thus its area is zero, hence the sum of areas of all these rectangles also zero. Am I correct?